# how to remove a gaps between cell in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below, and I want to remove the gaps between date and only want one row for per date.

```
     EVENT_TIME            POWER      SPEED      LATITUDE     LONGITUDE
2023-10-01 23:59:30       3529.2                 
2023-10-01 23:59:30                   59.2
2023-10-01 23:59:30                               214.9085
2023-10-01 23:59:30                                             11.2168
2023-10-01 23:59:00                   64.5 
2023-10-01 23:59:00       2258.2  
2023-10-01 23:59:00                               332.985  
2023-10-01 23:59:00                                             12.3658
2023-10-01 23:58:30       2236.2 
2023-10-01 23:58:30                   62.3
2023-10-01 23:58:30                               331.993
2023-10-01 23:58:30                                             15.2580
```

And this is how I want to be:

```
     EVENT_TIME            POWER      SPEED      LATITUDE     LONGITUDE
2023-10-01 23:59:30       3529.2       59.2      214.9085      11.2168
2023-10-01 23:59:00       2258.2       64.5      332.985       12.3658
2023-10-01 23:58:30       2236.2       62.3      331.993       15.2580
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function.

```py
from pandas import read_csv, to_datetime, notna


df = read_csv("data.csv")
df['EVENT_TIME'] = to_datetime(df['EVENT_TIME'])

result = df.groupby('EVENT_TIME').agg(lambda x: ', '.join(str(val) for val in x if notna(val))).reset_index()


print(result)
```